# Add Blob into Object in Javascript - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

I have a canvas in my app, which generates a `blob`.
The blob seems to be ok, so I guess the issue is not in there.

I have an AngularJs service, which needs to post to blob to the server:

```
function uploadBlobHeadshot(blob) {
    var url="/url";
    console.log(blob);
    var requestParams = {
      headshot_blob: blob
    };
    return $http.post(url, requestParams);
  }
```

However, when I check the object `requestParams` posted to the server, `headshot_blob` is an empty object, instead of the blob I saw in the above `console.log`.

So I guess I cannot set a blob as part of an object, but then, how can I post it to the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't realize. Just post my solution if someone is looking for:

```
  function uploadBlobHeadshot(blob) {
    var url = "/url";
    var uuid = sessionService.getAgentId();
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('headshot_blob', blob, 'imagem' + (new Date()).getTime());
    return $http.post(url', formData);
  }
```